# Is the sentence:"On seeing results, we are likely to gain experience.." grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, participles

I'm not really sure about the grammatical construction of the last sentence, because I know the grammar about using participle talking about sequences and that the main clause uses in past time. But is it possible to make the sentence like that one.

> ..Before doing something we try to learn and find out how the thing works. And then we put it on practice to see the results. **On seeing results**, we are likely to gain experience..

Comment: This reads like a narrative. I don't see any past tense here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On seeing the results, we are likely to gain experience.

There's nothing wrong with the sentence. The main clause isn't in the past; you are referring to a likely event in the future.  If you want to refer to a past event, you say:

On seeing the results, we were likely to gain experience.

Moreover, if you want to write the sentence in a more formal way, you can use the preposition "upon" instead of "on".

Answer (score 0):

Your last sentence might better read

> On seeing *the* results, we are likely to gain experience...
>   *Upon* seeing *the* results, we are likely to gain experience..

since you are talking about a specific set of results.

Comment: In this particular case I might use use "these" instead of "the", because it's referring to the results mentioned in the previous sentence.